# IntPtr.add doesn't exist

Tags: c#, memory, intptr

I want to make a simple program for reading a value of a program. I found a class on the internet which has everything i need to read/write data to the memory of a specified program. But im having a very annoying problem. I get this error: **Error CS0117  'IntPtr' does not contain a definition for 'Add"**. If you type IntPtr.add(....), intellisense won't show it. Whats going on :(

**NOTE: IntPtr.Zero and IntPtr.Size work perfectly.**

Here is the Code of the class,Its line 68-69:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProcessMemoryReaderLib
{
 internal class ProcessMemoryReaderApi
 {

    public const uint PROCESS_VM_READ = (0x0010);
    public const uint PROCESS_VM_WRITE = (0x0020);
    public const uint PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = (0x0008);
    public const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x0004;
    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x6;
    public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(UInt32 dwDesiredAccess, Int32 bInheritHandle, UInt32 dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, Out] byte[] buffer, UInt32 size, out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, UInt32 dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool VirtualProtectEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, UInt32 dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetKeyState(int vKey);

}

public class ProcessMemoryReader
{
    public ProcessMemoryReader()
    {
    }

    public static IntPtr FindDMAAddy(IntPtr hProc, IntPtr ptr, int[] offsets)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];

        foreach (int i in offsets)
        {
            ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(hProc, ptr, buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, out var read);

            ptr = (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            ? IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)), i)
            : ptr = IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)), i);
        }
        return ptr;
    }

    public Process ReadProcess
    {
        get
        {
            return m_ReadProcess;
        }
        set
        {
            m_ReadProcess = value;
        }
    }

    private Process m_ReadProcess = null;
    private IntPtr m_hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;

    public void OpenProcess()
    {
        m_hProcess = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.OpenProcess(ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_READ | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, 1, (uint)m_ReadProcess.Id);
    }

    public void CloseHandle()
    {
        int iRetValue;
        iRetValue = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.CloseHandle(m_hProcess);
        if (iRetValue == 0)
            throw new Exception("CloseHandle failed");
    }

    #region ReadMem

    public int ReadMem(int MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, out byte[] buffer)
    {
        IntPtr procHandle = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.OpenProcess(ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_READ | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, 1, (uint)m_ReadProcess.Id);
        if (procHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            buffer = new byte[0];
            return 0;
        }

        buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        IntPtr ptrBytesReaded;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, (IntPtr)MemoryAddress, buffer, bytesToRead, out ptrBytesReaded);
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.CloseHandle(procHandle);
        return ptrBytesReaded.ToInt32();
    }

    //We use this to
    public int ReadMultiLevelPointer(int MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, Int32[] offsetList)
    {
        IntPtr procHandle = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.OpenProcess(ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_READ | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, 1, (uint)m_ReadProcess.Id);
        IntPtr pointer = (IntPtr)0x0;
        //IF THE PROCESS isnt available we return nothing
        if (procHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        byte[] btBuffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        IntPtr lpOutStorage = IntPtr.Zero;

        int pointerAddy = MemoryAddress;
        //int pointerTemp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (offsetList.Length); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(
                    procHandle,
                    (IntPtr)(pointerAddy),
                    btBuffer,
                    (uint)btBuffer.Length,
                    out lpOutStorage);
            }
            pointerAddy = (BitConverter.ToInt32(btBuffer, 0) + offsetList[i]);
            //string pointerAddyHEX = pointerAddy.ToString("X");

            ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(
                procHandle,
                (IntPtr)(pointerAddy),
                btBuffer,
                (uint)btBuffer.Length,
                out lpOutStorage);
        }
        return pointerAddy;
    }

    public byte ReadByte(int MemoryAddress)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int read = ReadMem(MemoryAddress, 1, out buffer);
        if (read == 0)
            return new byte();
        else
            return buffer[0];
    }

    public int ReadInt(int MemoryAddress)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int read = ReadMem(MemoryAddress, 4, out buffer);
        if (read == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
    }

    public uint ReadUInt(int MemoryAddress)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int read = ReadMem(MemoryAddress, 4, out buffer);
        if (read == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
    }

    public float ReadFloat(int MemoryAddress)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        int read = ReadMem(MemoryAddress, 4, out buffer);
        if (read == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
    }

    public byte[] ReadAMem(IntPtr MemoryAddress, uint bytesToRead, out int bytesReaded)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];

        IntPtr ptrBytesReaded;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.ReadProcessMemory(m_hProcess, MemoryAddress, buffer, bytesToRead, out ptrBytesReaded);
        bytesReaded = ptrBytesReaded.ToInt32();
        return buffer;
    }

    internal byte[] ReadAMem(int p, int p_2, out int bytesReadSize)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion ReadMem

    #region WriteMem

    public int WriteMem(int MemoryAddress, byte[] buf)
    {
        IntPtr procHandle = ProcessMemoryReaderApi.OpenProcess(ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_READ | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_WRITE | ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, 1, (uint)m_ReadProcess.Id);
        if (procHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return 0;

        uint oldProtect;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.VirtualProtectEx(procHandle, (IntPtr)MemoryAddress, (uint)buf.Length, ProcessMemoryReaderApi.PAGE_READWRITE, out oldProtect);
        IntPtr ptrBytesWritten;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, (IntPtr)MemoryAddress, buf, (uint)buf.Length, out ptrBytesWritten);
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.CloseHandle(procHandle);
        return ptrBytesWritten.ToInt32();
    }

    public void WriteByte(int MemoryAddress, byte b)
    {
        WriteMem(MemoryAddress, new byte[] { b });
    }

    public void WriteInt(int MemoryAddress, int w)
    {
        byte[] buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(w);
        WriteMem(MemoryAddress, buf);
    }

    public void WriteUInt(int MemoryAddress, uint u)
    {
        byte[] buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(u);
        WriteMem(MemoryAddress, buf);
    }

    public void WriteFloat(int MemoryAddress, float f)
    {
        byte[] buf = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
        WriteMem(MemoryAddress, buf);
    }

    public void WriteAMem(IntPtr MemoryAddress, byte[] bytesToWrite, out int bytesWritten)
    {
        IntPtr ptrBytesWritten;
        ProcessMemoryReaderApi.WriteProcessMemory(m_hProcess, MemoryAddress, bytesToWrite, (uint)bytesToWrite.Length, out ptrBytesWritten);

        bytesWritten = ptrBytesWritten.ToInt32();
    }

    #endregion WriteMem

    #region Keys

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern short GetKeyState(Keys nVirtKey);

    public enum VirtualKeyStates : int
    {
        VK_LBUTTON = 0x01,
        VK_RBUTTON = 0x02,
        VK_CANCEL = 0x03,
        VK_MBUTTON = 0x04,

        //
        VK_XBUTTON1 = 0x05,

        VK_XBUTTON2 = 0x06,

        //
        VK_BACK = 0x08,

        VK_TAB = 0x09,

        //
        VK_CLEAR = 0x0C,

        VK_RETURN = 0x0D,

        //
        VK_SHIFT = 0x10,

        VK_CONTROL = 0x11,
        VK_MENU = 0x12,
        VK_PAUSE = 0x13,
        VK_CAPITAL = 0x14,

        //
        VK_KANA = 0x15,

        VK_HANGEUL = 0x15,  /* old name - should be here for compatibility */
        VK_HANGUL = 0x15,
        VK_JUNJA = 0x17,
        VK_FINAL = 0x18,
        VK_HANJA = 0x19,
        VK_KANJI = 0x19,

        //
        VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B,

        //
        VK_CONVERT = 0x1C,

        VK_NONCONVERT = 0x1D,
        VK_ACCEPT = 0x1E,
        VK_MODECHANGE = 0x1F,

        //
        VK_SPACE = 0x20,

        VK_PRIOR = 0x21,
        VK_NEXT = 0x22,
        VK_END = 0x23,
        VK_HOME = 0x24,
        VK_LEFT = 0x25,
        VK_UP = 0x26,
        VK_RIGHT = 0x27,
        VK_DOWN = 0x28,
        VK_SELECT = 0x29,
        VK_PRINT = 0x2A,
        VK_EXECUTE = 0x2B,
        VK_SNAPSHOT = 0x2C,
        VK_INSERT = 0x2D,
        VK_DELETE = 0x2E,
        VK_HELP = 0x2F,

        //
        VK_LWIN = 0x5B,

        VK_RWIN = 0x5C,
        VK_APPS = 0x5D,

        //
        VK_SLEEP = 0x5F,

        //
        VK_NUMPAD0 = 0x60,

        VK_NUMPAD1 = 0x61,
        VK_NUMPAD2 = 0x62,
        VK_NUMPAD3 = 0x63,
        VK_NUMPAD4 = 0x64,
        VK_NUMPAD5 = 0x65,
        VK_NUMPAD6 = 0x66,
        VK_NUMPAD7 = 0x67,
        VK_NUMPAD8 = 0x68,
        VK_NUMPAD9 = 0x69,
        VK_MULTIPLY = 0x6A,
        VK_ADD = 0x6B,
        VK_SEPARATOR = 0x6C,
        VK_SUBTRACT = 0x6D,
        VK_DECIMAL = 0x6E,
        VK_DIVIDE = 0x6F,
        VK_F1 = 0x70,
        VK_F2 = 0x71,
        VK_F3 = 0x72,
        VK_F4 = 0x73,
        VK_F5 = 0x74,
        VK_F6 = 0x75,
        VK_F7 = 0x76,
        VK_F8 = 0x77,
        VK_F9 = 0x78,
        VK_F10 = 0x79,
        VK_F11 = 0x7A,
        VK_F12 = 0x7B,
        VK_F13 = 0x7C,
        VK_F14 = 0x7D,
        VK_F15 = 0x7E,
        VK_F16 = 0x7F,
        VK_F17 = 0x80,
        VK_F18 = 0x81,
        VK_F19 = 0x82,
        VK_F20 = 0x83,
        VK_F21 = 0x84,
        VK_F22 = 0x85,
        VK_F23 = 0x86,
        VK_F24 = 0x87,

        //
        VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90,

        VK_SCROLL = 0x91,

        //
        VK_OEM_NEC_EQUAL = 0x92,   // '=' key on numpad

        //
        VK_OEM_FJ_JISHO = 0x92,   // 'Dictionary' key

        VK_OEM_FJ_MASSHOU = 0x93,   // 'Unregister word' key
        VK_OEM_FJ_TOUROKU = 0x94,   // 'Register word' key
        VK_OEM_FJ_LOYA = 0x95,   // 'Left OYAYUBI' key
        VK_OEM_FJ_ROYA = 0x96,   // 'Right OYAYUBI' key

        //
        VK_LSHIFT = 0xA0,

        VK_RSHIFT = 0xA1,
        VK_LCONTROL = 0xA2,
        VK_RCONTROL = 0xA3,
        VK_LMENU = 0xA4,
        VK_RMENU = 0xA5,

        //
        VK_BROWSER_BACK = 0xA6,

        VK_BROWSER_FORWARD = 0xA7,
        VK_BROWSER_REFRESH = 0xA8,
        VK_BROWSER_STOP = 0xA9,
        VK_BROWSER_SEARCH = 0xAA,
        VK_BROWSER_FAVORITES = 0xAB,
        VK_BROWSER_HOME = 0xAC,

        //
        VK_VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,

        VK_VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
        VK_VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
        VK_MEDIA_NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
        VK_MEDIA_PREV_TRACK = 0xB1,
        VK_MEDIA_STOP = 0xB2,
        VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
        VK_LAUNCH_MAIL = 0xB4,
        VK_LAUNCH_MEDIA_SELECT = 0xB5,
        VK_LAUNCH_APP1 = 0xB6,
        VK_LAUNCH_APP2 = 0xB7,

        //
        VK_OEM_1 = 0xBA,   // ';:' for US

        VK_OEM_PLUS = 0xBB,   // '+' any country
        VK_OEM_COMMA = 0xBC,   // ',' any country
        VK_OEM_MINUS = 0xBD,   // '-' any country
        VK_OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE,   // '.' any country
        VK_OEM_2 = 0xBF,   // '/?' for US
        VK_OEM_3 = 0xC0,   // '`~' for US

        //
        VK_OEM_4 = 0xDB,  //  '[{' for US

        VK_OEM_5 = 0xDC,  //  '\|' for US
        VK_OEM_6 = 0xDD,  //  ']}' for US
        VK_OEM_7 = 0xDE,  //  ''"' for US
        VK_OEM_8 = 0xDF,

        //
        VK_OEM_AX = 0xE1,  //  'AX' key on Japanese AX kbd

        VK_OEM_102 = 0xE2,  //  "<>" or "\|" on RT 102-key kbd.
        VK_ICO_HELP = 0xE3,  //  Help key on ICO
        VK_ICO_00 = 0xE4,  //  00 key on ICO

        //
        VK_PROCESSKEY = 0xE5,

        //
        VK_ICO_CLEAR = 0xE6,

        //
        VK_PACKET = 0xE7,

        //
        VK_OEM_RESET = 0xE9,

        VK_OEM_JUMP = 0xEA,
        VK_OEM_PA1 = 0xEB,
        VK_OEM_PA2 = 0xEC,
        VK_OEM_PA3 = 0xED,
        VK_OEM_WSCTRL = 0xEE,
        VK_OEM_CUSEL = 0xEF,
        VK_OEM_ATTN = 0xF0,
        VK_OEM_FINISH = 0xF1,
        VK_OEM_COPY = 0xF2,
        VK_OEM_AUTO = 0xF3,
        VK_OEM_ENLW = 0xF4,
        VK_OEM_BACKTAB = 0xF5,

        //
        VK_ATTN = 0xF6,

        VK_CRSEL = 0xF7,
        VK_EXSEL = 0xF8,
        VK_EREOF = 0xF9,
        VK_PLAY = 0xFA,
        VK_ZOOM = 0xFB,
        VK_NONAME = 0xFC,
        VK_PA1 = 0xFD,
        VK_OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE
    }

    public bool Keystate(Keys key)
    {
        int state = GetKeyState(key);
        if (state == -127 || state == -128)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    #endregion Keys
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other errors like on the using methods at top of module?  Did you try to build?  I'm not getting error.

Comment: Perhaps you've accidentally generated `IntPtr.cs`?

Comment: @jdweng No, I get this error only

Comment: @snipsnipsnip what do you mean?

Comment: @jdweng build the solution ofr the executable?

Comment: I ADDED A NOTE IN THE QUESTION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If found the solution. Im reall dumb. I wanted to make my program work on older versions of windows so i selected Framework 3.5. This version doesn't have the **IntPtr.Add**. I selected version 4.5 and now everything is fine!

Thanks everyone for the help